# App Clip Domain Status Error, Invocation Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, qr-code, apple-appclips

I'm working on building my first App Clip and am hoping to get thoughts on an issue I'm facing. The App Clip is meant to allow me to sell items from my own little personal shop without people having to download my full app first.

When I try to upload my App Clip to the App Store, I'm getting a Domain URL Status error of ["Unexpected Error"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fpr8.png)

My App has what I believe to be an appropriate Apple App Site Association file at the domain I've provided (I've checked it a number of times and the invocation works correctly in my developer local experience) so I don't see where that problem is coming from. This is what the JSON looks like on the [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN4jd.png) and also code below (with the identifying information changed to their generalized labels):

```
{
  "appclips": {
    "apps": [
      "TeamIDNumber.com.AppName.AppBundleID.Clip"
    ]
  }, 
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [], 
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "TeamIDNumber.com.AppName.AppBundleID.MarqetAppTest", 
        "paths": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In addition, when I try to create an Advanced App Clip Experience so that I can use QR code and NFC invocations, I get an error that ["This URL is not contained in your app's associated domains"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXmzg.png).

However, when I go into the [build metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKbsM.png), it clearly shows my website as an associated domain so I don't know whats causing that error.

The consequence of all this is that when I use an NFC tag (or scan the QR code using the iPhone QR reader) with my phone, I get taken to my website on Safari rather than the App Clip invocation coming up.

I submitted a ticket to Apple nearly 3 weeks ago and am being told they have no updates so checking if anyone here has thoughts. Any input appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved with the help of Apple! A bit embarrassing to say, but the error was that in the associated domains I had included an unnecessary space after the colon. So the associated domain was written as "appclips: marqetapp.com" when it should have been "appclips:marqetapp.com". Apple informed me that they are working to update their error messaging to make these kinds of issues clearer in the future.